# Cannot evaluate tensor using `eval()`: No default session is registered

Tags: python, tensorflow

i found this code to calculate the optimal portafolio for trading assets here

https://medium.com/stack-me-up/crypto-portfolio-optimization-with-python-and-tensorflow-an-approach-aa504578c799

here is the part of the code that causes me problems:

```
def minimize_volatility():

    # Define the model
    # Portfolio Volatility = Sqrt (Transpose (Wt.SD) * Correlation Matrix * Wt. SD)

    coin_weights = tf.Variable(np.full((len(coins), 1), 1.0 / len(coins))) # our variables
    weighted_std_devs = tf.multiply(coin_weights, std_deviations)

    product_1 = tf.transpose(weighted_std_devs)
    product_2 = tf.matmul(product_1, correlation_matrix)

    portfolio_variance = tf.matmul(product_2, weighted_std_devs)
    portfolio_volatility = tf.sqrt(tf.reduce_sum(portfolio_variance))


    # Run
    learn_rate = 0.01
    steps = 5000



    # Training using Gradient Descent to minimize variance
    train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learn_rate).minimize(portfolio_volatility)

    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
        for i in range(steps):
            sess.run(train_step)
            if i % 1000 == 0 :
                print("[round {:d}]".format(i))
                print("Weights", coin_weights.eval())
                print("Volatility: {:.2f}%".format(portfolio_volatility.eval() * 100))
                print("")
        
    return coin_weights.eval()

weights = minimize_volatility()

pretty_weights = pd.DataFrame(weights * 100, index = coins, columns = ["Weight %"])
pretty_weights
```

and here is the error

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-20-54aba198cebe> in <module>
     35     return coin_weights.eval()
     36 
---> 37 weights = minimize_volatility()
     38 
     39 pretty_weights = pd.DataFrame(weights * 100, index = coins, columns = ["Weight %"])

<ipython-input-20-54aba198cebe> in minimize_volatility()
     33                 print("")
     34 
---> 35     return coin_weights.eval()
     36 
     37 weights = minimize_volatility()

~/anaconda3/envs/tf-gpu/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variables.py in eval(self, session)
   1907       A numpy `ndarray` with a copy of the value of this variable.
   1908     """
-> 1909     return self._variable.eval(session=session)
   1910 
   1911   @property

~/anaconda3/envs/tf-gpu/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py in eval(self, feed_dict, session)
    729 
    730     """
--> 731     return _eval_using_default_session(self, feed_dict, self.graph, session)
    732 
    733 

~/anaconda3/envs/tf-gpu/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py in _eval_using_default_session(tensors, feed_dict, graph, session)
   5563     session = get_default_session()
   5564     if session is None:
-> 5565       raise ValueError("Cannot evaluate tensor using `eval()`: No default "
   5566                        "session is registered. Use `with "
   5567                        "sess.as_default()` or pass an explicit session to "

ValueError: Cannot evaluate tensor using `eval()`: No default session is registered. Use `with sess.as_default()` or pass an explicit session to `eval(session=sess)`
```

as far as i understand i should use a default session but dont know how to change the line

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
```

or so, in order to solve this problem

in advance thanks

Answer (score 0):

solved, the problem was the identation of the code on this line,

```
return coin_weights.eval(session=sess)
```

should be inside the

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
```